# Multiple Activities = multiple Apps installed?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar

I'm just getting started with the Android SDK and after I just understood how to open another view with a MenuItem. I'm now facing a problem that it is showing me my two activities as separated applications installed?

I've created a new activity and a new xml file (layout) and when I touch the menuItem in the ActionBar in my first view it opens the second view.

Any idea to work around that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have the `<intent-filter>` set as

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />    
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

for both activities. This will create a launcher icon for each and make each an entry point for your app

[Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/category-element.html)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you've included the following intent filter in both your Activities:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

This is meant to be put in only those Activities which you want shown in the app list.